# jQuery not being processed when returned via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that works when a form is submitted. It calls the page which contains some jquery stuff but it just returns the source code that isnt actually processed.

Below is the source of the page that gets called when the button is clicked. If i go to this page in the browser it displays a little progress bar but when it gets called via ajax this code gets returned but its returned as a string and doesnt appear to be processed.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#1" ).progressbar({
        value: 33
    });
});
</script>

<table style = "width:200px;">
<tr><td id = "1"></td></tr>
<tr><td id = "2"></td></tr>
<tr><td id = "3"></td></tr>
</table>
```

This is the ajax function

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#pollform").serialize(),
       success: function(data)
       {
           //im guessing this is where the issue lies 
           document.getElementById('pollbox').innerHTML = data;
       }
     });
```

Comment: Can you try `document.getElementById('pollbox').html(data);`?

Comment: @StijnGeukens  you mean: $('#pollbox').html(data);

Comment: I think you have to explain that a little better? If not the source of the file you're calling, what exactly are you expecting to get back?

Comment: ah yes that was the problem thanks guys

Comment: Yes, indeed :-); was focussed on the html part

Comment: check progress of ajax call in your browser Console

Comment: are you sure the success callback is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
 $('#pollbox').html(data);
```

http://api.jquery.com/html/